# Why do I have to access object attributes when using .map in this example

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to extract all the anchor from a page, but apparently I can't just return the same object as it is, I need to access one of its attributes

This is my example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://www.example.com/');

    const hrefs = await page.$$eval( 'a', anchors => anchors.map(a => a.href ));
    //const hrefs = await page.$$eval( 'a', anchors => anchors.map(a => a ));

    hrefs.forEach( h => console.log(h)); // prints the href
    //hrefs.forEach( h => console.log(h.href)); // prints undefined
    await browser.close();
})();
```

My first attempt (in comments ) was to just return the anchor so I can use all its properties later, but apparently that returns undefined always.

If I access one of its attributes then the map function contains something. I can even create a new object to add more properties

```
anchors.map(a => ({href:a.href, hostname:a.hostname}));
```

Comment: does this help ? `As per the doc, page.$eval() does not return ElementHandle or JSHandle: it returns the value returned by the function in the second argument after serialization/deserialization process. As x in your example is an HTML element, it is not serializable, so the empty object is returned instead.`
source https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2609

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha You should post that as the answer.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha it certainly does (please add it as answer). I tried to use `$('a')` instead which does return the ElementHandle, but I don't know how to retrieve the href from here

It looks like this https://gist.github.com/oscarryz/743bb1f5e4b953ec601fef4abfc8f808

Comment: @OscarRyz is it possible to use `JSON.stringify` here ?

Comment: `(node:43293) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Answer (score 3):

It's important to remember that, though Puppeteer does a great job blurring the boundaries between your app and Chromium, there is a serialization/de-serialization being performed when you get or send data using an `evaluate` call.

Long story short, I find that the best way to play with chromium is trying to solve everything in the evaluate function and return all the **data** you need.

This looks good to me

```js
const hrefs = await page.$$eval( 'a', anchors => anchors.map(a => a.href ));
hrefs.forEach( h => console.log(h)); // prints the href
```

Now, let's say that you do want to play with HTML elements. The best way to do that is by using the [$$ function](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.12.2/docs/api.md#pageselector-1)

```js
const anchors = await page.$$('a');
```

`anchors` won't be an array of HTML elements but an array of [ElementHandles](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.12.2/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle). An ElementHandle is basically a pointer to an element in Chromium.

Now you can pass that `ElementHandle` as an argument to an `evaluate` function.

```js
const promises = anchors.map(h => page.evaluate(h => h.href, h));
var hrefs = await Promise.all(promises);
hrefs.map(p => console.log(p));
```

As you can see, moving elements between chromium and your app is not as transparent as you might think but it's feasible.